# How to edit a package with atmospherejs.com in meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, atmosphere

To install the package with the atmosphere in meteor.js sufficient to use a single command. But let us assume that there is a need to edit a specific package for themselves. Now I needed to translate into another language package accounts-ui-bootstrap. Package code is in the appropriate folder in the directory .meteor. Everything works as it should, but after restarting the application server, all changes are rolled back to its original state. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new `JS or CSS` file on your `public/server` folder depends the case, and overwrite it